# Class Main$MapClass not found on EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-emr

i am trying to run my map-reduce job on EMR (Amazon) after i checked it on my local computer and i'm getting this error:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Main$MapClass not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1720)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:733)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Main$MapClass not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1626)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
... 8 more
```

this is the main function that define the Job configuration:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String inputLocation;
    String outputLocation;
    String includeStopWords;

    if (args.length > 2) {
        inputLocation = args[0];
        outputLocation = args[1];
        includeStopWords = args[2];
    }else{
        for(int i=0; i < args.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Missing Args!!\n" + "Number of args: "+ args.length+ "\n args[" + i+ "]:" + args[i]);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }


    // first job - count the 2 grams words by decade
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("includeStopWords", includeStopWords);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Job job = new Job(conf, "words count");
    System.out.println("before set classes:");  
    job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ReduceClass.class);
    System.out.println("after setting classes.");
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
//  job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputLocation));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputLocation));
    System.out.println("before wait to complition");
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    System.out.println("after wait to completion");


}
```

the code of the runner on EMR is:

```
public class Runner {
public static Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String minPmi;
    String relMinPmi;
    String language;
    String includeStopWords;
    if(args.length > 3){
        minPmi = args[0];
        relMinPmi = args[1];
        language = args[2];
        includeStopWords = args[3]; 
    }else{
        System.out.println("Missing Arguments!");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }


    //Jobs output locations
    String firstOutput = "s3n://dsp152ass2/outputs/first";
    String secondOutput = "s3n://dsp152ass2/outputs/second";
    String thirdOutput = "s3n://dsp152ass2/outputs/third";

    //Jobs jar location
    String firstJobJar = "s3n://dsp152ass2/jars/firstJob.jar";
    String secondJobJar = "s3n://dsp152ass2/jars/secondJob.jar";
    String thirdJobJar = "s3n://dsp152ass2/jars/thirdJob.jar";

    //select input corpus by language argument
    String corpus = "s3n://dsp152/output/eng-us-all-100k-2gram"; //TODO: change to the real input
    if(language.equalsIgnoreCase("heb")){
        corpus = "s3n://dsp152/output/heb-all-100k-2gram";
    }



    //Create EMR 
    AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(new FileInputStream(new File("credentials.properties")));
    AmazonElasticMapReduce mapReduce = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

    //Define hadoop Steps config
    HadoopJarStepConfig firstJobConfing = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
    .withJar(firstJobJar)  
    //.withMainClass("FirstMR.Main") // sec only runner
    .withArgs(corpus, firstOutput , includeStopWords);

    HadoopJarStepConfig secondJobConfing = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
    .withJar(secondJobJar)
//  .withMainClass("Main")
    .withArgs(firstOutput +"/part-r-00000" , secondOutput);

    HadoopJarStepConfig thirdJobConfing = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
    .withJar(thirdJobJar) 
    //.withMainClass("Main")
    .withArgs(secondOutput+"/part-r-00000", thirdOutput , minPmi, relMinPmi); 


    //Define step config
    StepConfig firstJobStep = new StepConfig()
    .withName("firstJobStep")
    .withHadoopJarStep(firstJobConfing)
    .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW");

    StepConfig secondJobStep = new StepConfig()
    .withName("secondJobStep")
    .withHadoopJarStep(secondJobConfing)
    .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW");

    StepConfig thirdJobStep = new StepConfig()
    .withName("thirdJobStep")
    .withHadoopJarStep(thirdJobConfing)
    .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW");


    //Define job flow
    JobFlowInstancesConfig instances = new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
    .withInstanceCount(1) //TODO: change to 2 - 10
    .withMasterInstanceType(InstanceType.M1Large.toString())
    .withSlaveInstanceType(InstanceType.M1Large.toString())
    .withHadoopVersion("2.2.0").withEc2KeyName("dsp152ass2")
    .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
    .withPlacement(new PlacementType("us-east-1b"));



    //Define run flow
    RunJobFlowRequest runFlowRequest = new RunJobFlowRequest()
    .withName("DSPextractCollections")  
    .withInstances(instances)
    .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
    .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
    .withSteps(firstJobStep,secondJobStep,thirdJobStep)
    .withLogUri("s3n://dsp152ass2/logs/"); 


    //Run the jobs
    RunJobFlowResult runJobFlowResult = mapReduce.runJobFlow(runFlowRequest);
    String jobFlowId = runJobFlowResult.getJobFlowId();
    System.out.println("### WORKFLOW SUCCESSFULLY ADDED: \n" + "\t" + jobFlowId);

}
```

}

my project structure:
[image: project structure]

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How you are executing your job on EMR? Have you added your main class in class path? Please provide the way you are executing your jar.

Comment: Can you attach the entire `Main` class, as well as the way you're executing the job? Also, what is your debug verbosity?

Comment: i am executing the job on EMR with the Runner code i've added now to the question.

Comment: I meant *logging* and not *debugging* obviously :)

Comment: the logging level is debug. (log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG)

Comment: Try adding  class in your classpath. If you are using pom.xml then try adding it into your project build manifest entries.

Comment: What is the project structure? Do you have **separate** `Main`, `MapClass` and `ReduceClass` classes, or are they nested inside `Main`?

Comment: the MapClass, ReduceClass are nesten inside Main class.

Comment: Try changing `MapClass` to `Main.MapClass` (same for `Main.ReduceClass`), or see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are steps that can solve the resolution problem:

1. Create separate `Mapper` and `Reducer` classes.
2. Create a package name for the classes and use it and not the default package (`foo.Main`, `foo.MapClass` ...).
3. When you're in Eclipse, try the  "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" option, instead of "Package required libraries into generated JAR". This may solve classes not being found (make sure you copy everything eclipse generated).

**Tip:** EMR has specific settings that are not like running a local (and probably pseudo-distributed) deployment. Make sure those are correct by following [AWS's guide.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-what-is-emr.html)

[image: Extract required libraries into generated jar]